# Automatically insert a white space while user enter text into a input text

Tags: inputtext

I created a input text field, do you think it is possible to automatically insert a blank space every 4 characters while the user types in the field? I wanted to reproduce what usually happens in many banking applications when the iban is entered. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi , I think this discussion would answer your question [How to Add space between every 4 characters in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53427046/how-to-add-space-between-every-4-characters-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning using an LWC you could recreate the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73745068/how-to-add-space-between-every-4-numbers). So full credit to that guy :)

A working example which I managed to implement quickly was the below:

HTML:

```html
<template>
    <lightning-input
        id={id}
        value={ibanValue}
        onchange={onIbanChange}
    ></lightning-input>
</template>
```

JS:

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";

const formatNumber = (number) => number.split("").reduce((seed, next, index) => {
  if (index !== 0 && !(index % 4)) seed += " ";
  return seed + next;
}, "");


export default class IBANTextComponent extends LightningElement {
  @api id="ibanComp";
  ibanValue;

  onIbanChange(event) {
    this.ibanValue = formatNumber(event.target.value.replaceAll(" ", ""));
  }
}
```